# Suppress exit signal in Boost.Test

Tags: c++, windows, boost-test

I would like to test a method in my program, which handles shutdown of the application. At the end this method calls `exit(0);`

As expected this shuts also my test application down.

Is there a possibility to catch the exit signal in this particular unit test, so the shutdown of the test application can be avoided?

Comment: The better idea would be to end the program by returning from `main`.

Comment: @VTT Although I agree this is a legacy application and changing this would require serious refactoring.

Comment: You can use atexit() to call some function(s) on exit, but I doubt that it is possible to intercept exit() call (I mean, normally). BTW, why 'windows' tag?

Comment: I don't mind a platform-independent solution, but the application currently runs under Windows only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no way to prevent exit() from ending the program, you will have to change the legacy application in some way or another.

For a similar problem I used the following solution:

- A class that provides the feature I want to use/change through a public, static function, e.g.
  `static void Wrapper::exit( int exit_code);`
- A base class that declares the interface of the features I want to provide:
  `virtual void Base::exit( int exit_code) = 0;`
- Then a class, derived from the base class `Base`, that implements the normal behaviour:
  `void OsImpl::exit( int exit_code) { ::exit( exit_code); }`
- The `Wrapper` class finally contains a pointer to the implementation to use, by default an object of `OsImpl`, but that can be replaced by e.g. a `TestImpl` that does nothing.
  `static void Wrapper::setImpl( Base* handler);`
- Finally, in the application replace `::exit( 0);` by `Wrapper::exit( 0);`
  When run "normally", the application will stop as before, but in your test program you can make it return to the test function.

I know this is quite condensed, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I like the idea

Comment: I ended up just making a test subclass of my class under test and excluding the exit call, because this approach would lead to a stack overflow exception at shutdown. But I will use this approach for similar problems.

Comment: Well, you have to make sure that OsImpl::exit() calls ::exit() and not itself again ... The easiest way to achive that is to use namespaces and/or different function names.

Comment: You're right, I missed the '::'. Was obviously too late yesterday evening ;-)

Comment: So I reworked it again to your solution and this time I used `::exit()` and it works like a charm. Thanks again!